# How to exclude some files not matching certain extensions with grep?

Tags: grep, wildcards

I want to output all lines containing the word `OK` recursively from a directory. But there are a few extensions which I need to exclude from the result:

```
*~
*.map
*.js except *.debug.js
```

I tried:

```
grep -r --exclude={*~,*.map} "OK" /some/dir
```

Except that I don't know how to remove from the result all those non-debug `.js` files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just pass that through a second `grep` to remove them:

```
grep -r --exclude={\*~,\*.map} "OK" bar/ | grep -vP '(?<!debug)\.js'
```

The `-v` reverses the match, printing lines that don't match the pattern and the `-P` enables Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which let us use [negative lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This particular regex, will match `.js` that is *not* prececeded by `debug` which means (since we are inverting the matches) that only those `.js` files will be printed.

However, as @QuestionOverflow pointed out int the comments, that could have the unintended side effect of filtering out *lines* that contain `OK` and `js` since the `grep -v` is applied to the entire output, not only the file name. To avoid that, just add a colon (that's what `grep` uses to separate file names from file contents):

```
grep -r --exclude={*~,*.map} "OK" bar/ | grep -vP '(?<!debug).js:'
```

That will still fail if your input line contains `foo.js:` or if your file name contains `:`. So, to be sure, use a different approach:

```
grep -Tr --exclude={*~,*.map} "OK" bar/ | grep -vP '(?<!debug).js\t'
```

The `-T` causes `grep` to print a tab between the file name and the file contents. So, if we simply add a `\t` to the end of the regex, it will only match against file names, and not the contents of the line.

Still, [using `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125029/22222) might make more sense regardless.

Comment: Would I be inadvertently excluding lines in those files that I want, but containing both `OK` and `.js` on the same line?

Comment: @QuestionOverflow ah, yes indeed, good catch. See updated answer.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Have to accept yours since I ask specifically for grep. Thanks.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow you're very welcome. In general though, `find` is probably better for this kind of thing. Getting the right `grep` can be tricky as you pointed out :).

Comment: Your solutions fail if one has the `failglob` option set in the shell:  `bash: no match: --exclude=*~`  You need to quote your GLOB pattern arguments to `--exclude` to hide them from shell expansion, e.g. `--exclude={\*~,\*.map}`

Comment: Adding the TAB to the regexp decreases the probability that your solutions will fail based on a regexp match inside the file content, but it still incorrectly fails to find all lines that contain the letters `js` followed by a TAB.  Also, since you don't quote the period in `.js`, you also incorrectly exclude strings such as `ajs`, `bjs`, `cjs`, etc. followed by a TAB: `printf "foo 'ajs\t' bar" | grep -vP '(?<!debug).js\t'`

Comment: @IDAllen very good point on the `.`, fixed and thanks. I don't understand your other point though. I am not looking for `js`, I am looking for `OK` and want to exclude _files_ that end in `js` unless they end in `debug.js`. Am I still missing something?

Comment: @IDAllen and I just read your previous comment. Thanks again, that should have been obvious, but I blindly copied the OPs version.

Answer (score 8):

I'd use `find` to locate the files and pipe the result through `xargs`:

```
$ find . -type f \! -name "*~" \
                 \! -name "*.map" \
                 \! \( -name "*.js" -and \! -name "*.debug.js" \) \
         -print0 | xargs -0 grep "OK"
```

This searches for every file *not* matching "`*~`", "`*.map`" or "`*.js` but not `*.debug.js`".

Using `find` you can easily search for rather complex rules and this approach saves you from accidentally removing false positives as could happen with double `grep`.

Comment: Nice answer too :)

Comment: Yes, this is probably the best way, +1. You could also use  `-exec grep OK {} +` instead of `xargs` and avoid an extra program.

Comment: @IDAllen no, note that I suggested `-exec +` not `-exec \;`, that will run as few commands as possible, much like `xargs`.

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh` you can do:

```
setopt extendedglob
grep OK some/dir/**/^(*~|*.map|(^*debug).js)
```

Provided of course the argument list isn't too long, in which case you can always do:

```
printf '%s\0' some/dir/**/^(*~|*.map|(^*debug).js) | xargs -0 grep OK
```

Comment: Also, you could make the last one `zsh`-only: `autoload zargs` and `zargs some/dir/**/^(*~|*.map|(^*debug).js) -- grep OK`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep). By default it ignores hidden files and respects your `.gitignore` file.

You can specify the inclusion or exclusion rules by using the following parameters:

> <sup>`-g`/`--glob GLOB` Include or exclude files and directories for searching that match the given glob.</sup>
>
> <sup>`-t`/`--type TYPE` Only search files matching TYPE. Multiple type flags may be provided.</sup>
>
> <sup>`-T`/`--type-not TYPE` Do not search files matching TYPE.</sup>
>
> <sup>Use the `--type-list` flag to list all available types.</sup>

Here are few simple examples:

```
rg -Tjs "OK"                              # Excludes *.js, *.jsx, *.vue files.
rg -tpy "OK"                              # Includes Python files.
rg --type-add 'map:*.map' -tmap PATTERN   # Excludes *.map files.
rg -g '!*.js' -g '*.debug.js' PATTERN     # Excludes *.js apart of *.debug.js.
```

Here is the complete solution to exclude `*.~`, `*.map`, `*.js`, but not `*.debug.js`:

```
rg -g '*.*' -g '!*.~' -g '!*.map' -g '!*.js' -g '*.debug.js' "OK"
```

---

Testing:

```
$ touch file.~ file.map file.js file.debug.js file.txt file.md
$ rg --files
file.debug.js
file.js
file.map
file.md
file.txt
$ rg -g '*.*' -g '!*.~' -g '!*.map' -g '!*.js' -g '*.debug.js' --files
file.debug.js
file.md
file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind seeing the output slightly out of order (if you do, you can sort it):

```
grep -r --exclude={*~,*.map,*.js} "OK" /some/dir **/*.debug.js
```

This requires that your shell supports `**` for recursive globbing: zsh does out of the box, bash does after you run `shopt -s globstar`, ksh93 does after you run `set -o globstar`.

Without `**` support in the shell, you can use two grep commands:

```
grep -r --exclude={*~,*.map,*.js} "OK" /some/dir
grep -r --include=*.debug.js "OK" /some/dir
```